# How to delete an area of a surface

Tags: plotting, graphics, interpolation

I have a [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/rdv5adk5mqcmm1r/lvo.dat) which defines a three-dimensional surface.

```
data = Import["lvo.dat", "Table"];
L1 = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
     ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", PlotRange -> All];
```

Then we define a simple curve on that surface

```
dE = 30;
dataf3 = {{7.59, 4.8, -3407 + dE}, {7.82, 4.75, -3393 + dE}, 
          {8.05, 4.72, -3384 + dE}, {8.22, 4.71, -3381 + dE}, 
          {8.33, 4.71, -3381 + dE}, {8.51, 4.72, -3384 + dE}, 
          {8.72, 4.75, -3395 + dE}, {8.94, 4.8, -3413 + dE}};

f3 = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[Length[dataf3]], dataf3}], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 3];

n = 1000;
dataf33 = Table[f3[u], {u, 1, Length[dataf3], (Length[dataf3] - 1)/(n - 1)}];

L2 = ListPointPlot3D[dataf33, PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, PointSize[0.01]}}];
```

Therefore we have

```
plot = Show[{L1, L2}, ImageSize -> 500, ViewPoint -> {1.9, -1.6, 2.8}]
```

[image]

My question: Is there an easy way to delete the area of the surface which lies inside and below the yellow parabolic curve?

By the way, I use version 9.0 of Mathematica.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `RegionFunction`

Comment: @Wjx But the analytical expression of the yellow curve is not known...

Comment: How did you have this yellow line? You can set the `PlotRange->{Your_minlevel,Your_maxlevel}` and `ClippingStyle->None`

Comment: @Rom38 `PlotRange` has a global effect to the entire surface. I could define manually the limits of the vertical axis and delete the area inside the curve but I will also loose some of the corners of the surface. I need a local treatment.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, this re-turn us to a question how did you define the yellow curve? You can solve the equation on interpolating functions for this curve setting the certain height and the domain for x,y.

Comment: @Rom38 I do not fully understand your point. Could you please explain it further in an answer?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I guess that he what means is you cannot determine the curve with just a few point right? You need a method to interpolate the points and create a analytical curve to plot. If you can do the same when determining the `RegionFunction`, you get a analytical expression just as you would like to have~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-written the answer to the simplest case of solution but it is going by the previously depicted way:

You can define the cut-off region function as

```
RegionFunction->Function[{x, y, z}, (6 < x < 11) && (4 < y < f3[x]) && (z > -3380)
```

Where the f3 is a bit another interpolation of your line points:

```
f3 = Interpolation[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]} & /@ dataf3, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

Further,

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
L1 = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", PlotRange -> All, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, 
     z}, (6 < x < 11) && (4 < y < f3[x]) && (z > -3380)]]
```

The switched off error-message appears due to certain mismatch in definitions of the boundaries of interpolation function and the region definitions for region-function.
[image]

Comment: If I add this to `L1` the area is not deleted.

Comment: Could you upload somewhere your data set to test the solution directly? I've tested this with arbitrary surface and it was working good.

Comment: In the first line of my original post there is a link to the full data which define the surface.